# How to format code easily?

Tags: discussion

Can you tell me how to write code in Stack Overflow easily as it's hard to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> every time I write a sentence?

I have checked the advanced help and I didn't get it.

Comment: What-da-ya-know, I didn't even know about **Ctrl+K**.   If your intent is to insert a _block of code_, then you prefix each line with **four spaces**

Comment: paste your code and insert a 4-char whitespace vector on every line via `paste`. If it was good enough for your elders, its good enough for you, young man! But I do agree that there should be some sort of hint about `CTRL-K` in a prominent position.

Comment: Ask this on meta

Comment: It's so hard to do with the left hand only, though.

Comment: if he asks it on meta, will he need to indent or format his question in a difficult manner?

Comment: You shouldn't be composing very much code in the editor anyway. You should be composing somewhere that you can test it, then copy-pasting it verbatim into the answer box. Highlighting a few blocks of code and hitting Ctrl+K isn't too much effort.

Comment: There's a great [user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts) just for this purpose

Answer (score 6):

You can write, or paste, the entire code first in the SO editor, select it all and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or press the `{}` button, to indent the whole block, which will also highlight the code.

A block of code that is indented four spaces and surrounded by blank lines is highlighted, and that button will do just that.

Comment: I didn't know that about the whole block either :)  Dunno who down-voted you.  +1

Comment: Interesting how the downvotes on the _question_ (-2:0) disappeared after the move but not on the _answer_.  That's a bit unfair.  :(

Comment: That's just how it is, Roy. Fortunately meta-downvotes don't count as rep. Unfortunately meta-upvotes don't either. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

When including code in a post, make sure that you are always including the smallest amount of relevant code possible. This will save people time when trying to answer your question, and as a result will save you time getting your question answered.

There are two great resources available for narrowing the scope of your problem at "*[Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)*" and "*[WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)*".

Once you have code ready, when you include it in your post ensure that the spacing is accurate. Often when copy/pasted it will come out funky:

function basic(){
    var myvar = "hello";
    return myvar + "world";
}

If you look at the above, it was written without indentation, but often that is how the paste comes in.

Basically you are going to need to manually edit the code indentation, often there is not a good automated solution. Treating tabs as 4 spaces is the best way to go, because the first "tab" (4 spaces) will ensure that the code formatter is triggered and it will show up as "code" in the render.

```
function basic(){
    var myvar = "hello";
    return myvar + "world";
}
```

Often what I will do is copy 4 spaces, and then just paste them every time I need a tab to display. This makes it quick to format the code.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I use my code editor (vim or Sublime Text) to edit my code until it's ready for posting, then select it all, indent by four spaces, then copy and paste it into the editor for questions/answers. It works like a charm.

I do much the same when editing text in questions or answers. It's much more convenient than the simple editor on the page.